# CS1022 : Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected for program.cs file in ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Creating an ASP.NET Core MVC application in VS2022.

The build throws the error shown here, for `program.cs` file. But I'm not seeing any red indication in the class file.

[image: Error while build]

This is the code of `program.cs`:

```
using Fluent.Infrastructure.FluentModel;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

//var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

And I'm getting this error message on 'RUN'

[image]

Can anyone help me resolve this issue? I've been struggling with this error for a long time.

Comment: If you still can't fix the issue, please share the project for us. And don't forget to hide your sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow below steps, I think you could fix the issue.**

**1. Move you code here like the picture below.**

[image]

**2. Delete `.vs`, `bin`, `obj` folder.**

[image]

[image]

**3. Expand the Denpendencies to check the warning.**

[image]